# Is there any more technical information about the iPad/iPhone charge management feature?

Tags: iphone, ipad, battery, charging

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208710), a new "charge management" feature which reduces the maximum capacity of an iPhone or iPad device when it is plugged in for prolonged periods of time. This was quite interesting to me, but it did not include any detail at all. Is there any more technical information about this, such as how long it takes of being plugged in for this feature to be enabled, or the maximum charge capacity that it is limited to when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

It’s explained right below the option in settings by Apple: “To reduce battery agin, iPhone learns from your daily charging routine so it can wait to finish charging past 80% until you need to use it.”

It works best when you have a set schedule for yourself, as when you are unpredictable, it tends to just charge at 100% all the time.

Charging to 80% prolongs the life of lithium-ion batteries by nearly double as charging to 80% uses 50% of a life-cycle and charging the remains 20% (the slowest part of charging) uses the remaining 50% of the life-cycle.

Apple goes more into depth in their “[Batteries: Why Lithium Ion](https://www.apple.com/batteries/why-lithium-ion/)” page